# Sybase Case Statement syntax error

Tags: sql, case, sybase

Im trying to run a case statement query in sysbase but i keep running into a error. The query is here

```
CASE WHEN table.TYPPAYT is '04' then 'Cash on delivery'
ELSE table.TYPPAYT
END
```

I have also tried it like this.

```
CASE WHEN table.TYPPAYT is '04' then 'Cash on delivery'
ELSE table.TYPPAYT
END
```

Both of these return syntax error near '04'

When i run it like this it works but its not what i want

```
CASE WHEN table.TYPPAYT is  then 'Cash on delivery'
ELSE table.TYPPAYT
END
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `=` not `is`. `is` is only used for `IS NULL`/`IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way using `=` operator

```
CASE WHEN table.TYPPAYT = '04' then 'Cash on delivery'
ELSE table.TYPPAYT
END
```

or using `in`

```
CASE WHEN table.TYPPAYT in ('04') then 'Cash on delivery'
ELSE table.TYPPAYT
END
```